# Gold linker ld.gold -plugin : unknown option

Tags: linker, ld, gold-linker

I'm trying to build Google's ligjingle following the [Getting started](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started) steps, and I've reached the "Building" section.

When I issue either

```
ninja -C out/Debug
```

or

```
ninja -C out/Release
```

I get the following error : 
[I posted the output in pastebin too, if you prefer](http://pastebin.com/LBD6XSL5)

```
ninja -C out/Debug
ninja: Entering directory `out/Debug'
[3/2606] LINK genmacro
FAILED: cc -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--fatal-warnings -pthread -Wl,-z,noexecstack -fPIC -B/home/nschoe/workspace/webrtc/jingle/trunk/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -m64 -Wl,--icf=none -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--gdb-index -o genmacro -Wl,--start-group obj/third_party/yasm/source/patched-yasm/tools/genmacro/genmacro.genmacro.o  -Wl,--end-group 
/home/nschoe/workspace/webrtc/jingle/trunk/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin/ld.gold: -plugin: unknown option
/home/nschoe/workspace/webrtc/jingle/trunk/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin/ld.gold: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[3/2606] CC obj/net/third_party/nss/ssl/libssl.sslauth.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I tried

```
ld.gold --help | grep "plugin"
```

and got :

```
--plugin PLUGIN             Load a plugin library
--plugin-opt OPTION         Pass an option to the plugin
```

So I suppose the error I'm getting is because somewhere in the code, ld.gold is called with `-plugin xxx` rather than `--plugin xxx`

I have been "*playing*" with `grep -Hr` and different combinations of "plugin" to try to find the problem, but so far I haven't found anything. I suppose it is hidden somewhere in a Makefile.

Comment: if you want to comment multiple lines, indent them by 4 spaces.  if you want to comment a single line, surround them with just a single backtick on either side.

Comment: Okay, will do. Sorry.

Comment: no need to apologize, I just can't imagine it's easy/enjoyable to do what you've been doing here for code formatting haha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is not that the `-plugin` option should be `--plugin`. `ld.gold`
accepts both options if it accepts either of them.

But it only accepts either of them *if* the build of `binutils` has been
configured with `--enable-plugins`. [Documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html).

When you run `ld.gold --help | grep "plugin"` the output shows that `--plugin` is
a recognized option.

Therefore the problem appears to be this:-

`/home/nschoe/workspace/webrtc/jingle/trunk/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin/ld.gold`
has *not* been configured with `--enable-plugins`

When you run `ld.gold --help | grep "plugin"` you are executing the first `ld.gold`
that is found on your `PATH`. It is probably `/usr/bin/ld.gold` from your distro. You
can find out by running:

```
which ld.gold
```

Anyhow, it isn't
`/home/nschoe/workspace/webrtc/jingle/trunk/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin/ld.gold`
and it is an `ld.gold` that *has* been configured with `--enable-plugins`

If you `cd` into `/home/nschoe/workspace/webrtc/jingle/trunk/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin/`
and run:

```
 ./ld.gold -plugin
```

you will get:

```
./ld.gold: -plugin: unknown option
```

To fix the problem the ideal solution is to rebuild `/home/nschoe/workspace/webrtc/jingle/trunk/third_party/binutils`
as per [that Documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html)

If you cannot rebuild these third party `binutils` from source then it will
probably work if you just copy the system `ld.gold` detected by `which` over the one in the
third party `binutils`, or delete/rename the third party one and replace it with a symlink
to the system one. There is an outside chance that either of the these hacks
would cause you some obscure breakage.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for that explanation.
You're totally right : the Linux_x64/Release/bin version doesn't have plugin support (which is very weird because this is Google's own code that downloaded (and built ?) it, and they use it to link the files... )
Anyway I'm following the documentation to try rebuild binutils with plugin support, if that fails, I'll try to make a symlink to my /usr/bin/ld.gold.

Anyway thanks again and I'll post here again to tell if I managed.

Comment: Yeah it worked, thank again : you really helped out here.
I still can't compile as I get the error : 
```
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-’
```

But that definitely solved my problem with ld.gold, thanks.
(Any idea why the new error ?)